# How to generate all orders of variable combinations for formula in R

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to run the adonis function on some of my data. However, the order of the variables in the formula (changes the results of the analysis.

For replication, I have included 3 of my variables of interest in the example below that I would like to include in the model.

Is there a way I can write a code that generates combinations of the variables where each one is first, second, third etc.

```
variables <- c("stage", "type", "treatment")
formula1 <- adonis(Data ~ stage + type + treatment, data = metadata)
```

I tried this to generate all combinations:

```
n <- length(variables)
id <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i)combn(1:n,i,simplify=FALSE)),recursive=FALSE)
formulas <- sapply(id,function(i) paste("Data~",paste(variables[i],collapse="+")))
```

But it doesn't change the order of the variables in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

To generate all the formulas you need to use permutations instead of combinations. The difference is that in permutations the order matters so (1,2,3) is not the same as (3,1,2) wheres in combinations the order doesn't matter so the above two sets would be considered equivalent.
The `gtools` package has a `permutations` function to generate all the different permutations.

```
library(gtools)
variables <- c("stage", "type", "treatment")
perms <- permutations(n = length(variables), r = length(variables), variables)
formulas <- apply(perms, 1, function(r){
  form1 <- as.formula(paste("Data ~", paste(r, collapse = "+")))
  
})
```